# rebase conflicted, merged commits in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase

I have just finished developing a new feature on its own branch (branch `feature`) consisting of a dozen or so commits. After running all my tests, I merged this branch into `master` and resolved *many* merge conflicts. The process took quite awhile. Only *after* I finished merging do I realize that I never rebased any of the commits in the `feature` branch, which is generally my practice.

In short, now I have:

```
(feature)   B-C-D
(master) A-/     \-E (merge commit in master)
```

but I want to have:

```
   F
A-/ \-D
```

where F = B + C + D "squashed" together.

The way I was going about this was to create another branch `master_prime` from `master` starting at commit `A`. Then, switch to the `feature` branch and accomplish all the commit squashing I want. Finally, merge `feature` into `master_prime`. The only issue is that I'll have to resolve all the merge conflicts again. Is there a way I can replay/pick out the merge commit `E` so that this isn't necessary?

I have also attempted `git rebase --preserve-merges -i <A>` as well as `git rebase -i <A>`, which don't allow me to rebase the commits I want or make me deal with  merge conflicts again, respectively.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what about `git rebase --preserve-merges -i <A>` isn't working for you? I was able to run that exact command and have B, C, D, and E available for rebase operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git read-tree` to reuse your resolution of the merge conflicts.

I'm assuming you merged `feature` into `master`. If you merged `master` into `feature`, use `master^2` instead of `master^` (and vice versa).

1. Make a backup of your merge commit.

   ```
   git branch merge-backup master
   ```
2. Squash the commits in `feature`. Make sure you don't accidentally change anything.

   ```
   git checkout feature
   # ... squash the commits ...
   git diff master^2
   ```
3. Get rid of the old merge commit.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard master^
   ```
4. Merge the squashed `feature` branch into `master`, reusing your old conflict resolution.

   ```
   git merge feature
   git read-tree --reset -u merge-backup
   git commit
   ```
5. If you are pleased with the results, delete the backup branch.

   ```
   git branch -D merge-backup
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are probably a number of ways to accomplish what you want, but a couple of things first:

1) you don't need a new master branch if you don't want to.  You can use `git reset` to change the point of the current master branch back to `A` or something without needing a newly named branch.  (you can also create your new `master_prime`, do what you want to get it to "the best place on earth" and the rename `master` to `master_old` and rename `master_prime` to `master`.

But that's all besides the point because it's not really what you're asking.

What you want is feature branch `feature` with all the needed changes from `A` to `D` in it.  And...  the changes required to make the merge.  At this point you probably want to rebase, as that will still be a pain.  But you can do your squashing and copy your merge edits into place (using `reset` instead of a new branch left as an exercise to the reader):

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b feature2
git cherry-pick B..D
... squash away here ...
git cherry-pick E              # copies the merge pain in
git checkout master
git merge feature2
```

I **think**